# Regular expression to match IP addresses

Tags: php, regex, preg-grep

I have `file.txt` which contains this data:

```
livebox.home (192.168.1.1)
set-top-box41.home (192.168.1.10)
pc38.home (192.168.1.11)
pc43.home (192.168.1.12)
pc39.home (192.168.1.15)
```

I want to extract the IP of `pc39.home`. I have used this regular expression but it not work:

```
preg_grep("#^[a-z]{2}39.[a-z]{4} \d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1}\.\d{2}#",$myfile);
```

The result should be `192.168.1.15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this you can just change the $search if you want to caputure any of the other IPs.

```
$search = "pc39\.home";
preg_match("/" . $search ." \(([\d.]+)\)/", $myfile, $out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}39\.[a-z]{4} \(([\d.]+)~m', $myfile_contents, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA5aR0/2)

I added a `\(` to match a literal `(` and used a capturing group around `[\d.]+` (*1 or more digits or dots*) that matches the IP that can be retrieved using `[1]` index in `$matches`. The `~m` enables a multiline mode so that `^` could match the beginning of a line, not just the string start.

**UPDATE**

If you need to create a dynamic regex with a literal string in it, you should think about using `preg_quote`:

```
$myfile = file('file.txt');
$search = "pc39.home";           // <= a literal string, no pattern
foreach ($myfile as $lineContent)
{
     $lines=preg_match('/' . preg_quote($search, "/") . ' \(([\d.]+)\)/', $lineContent, $out);
     echo($out[1]);
}
```

You also need a single quoted literal in `' \(([\d.]+)\)/'` since the `\` must be literal `\` symbols (yes, PHP resolves `\` as a literal `\` with non-existing escape sequences, but why put it to PHP?).

Answer (score 1):

the solution is:

```
$myfile = file('file.txt');
            $search = "pc39\.home";
            foreach ($myfile as $lineContent)
            {
               $lines=preg_match("/" . $search ." \(([\d.]+)\)/", $lineContent, $out);
               echo($out[1]);
            }
```

Comment: If you want to use a variable as a literal in a regex, you can just use `preg_quote`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('anyfile.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $fileContent);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'pc39.home') !== false) {
        $ipStart = strpos($line, '(') + 1;
        $ipEnd = strpos($line, ')');
        $ip = substr($line, $ipStart, $ipEnd - $ipStart);
        echo "IP of pc39.home: " . $ip;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of search you can use regex as asked