# Regular expression php not works

Tags: php

I have this text and i like to detect the adresse ip with `preg_match`

```
Nmap scan report for pc39.home (192.168.1.15)
```

you find there the regular expression that i have used but it not work the retrun is 0.

```
$regex=preg_match('/^\(([\d.]+)\)$/', $scan, $out);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294578/regular-expression-to-match-ip-addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong:

```
^\(([\d.]+)\)$
^    here    ^
```

You are binding the result to the beginning and the end of the input so it will only match if there is *only* an ip address between parenthesis and nothing else.

You only need:

```
\(([\d.]+)\)
```

You can check it [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1gU7/1).

Comment: Thank you $re = "/\\(([\\d.]+)\\)/"; 
     $regex=preg_match($re, $scan, $out);

Answer (score 0):

dot is every char. You need to escape it.

```
$scan = 'Nmap scan report for pc39.home (192.168.1.15)';
$regex=preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $scan, $out);
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Not inside a character class `[...]`